# how can i solve munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer on regfree(&regex)

Tags: c, regex

Hello im getting `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`
on
`regfree(&regexCompiled);` 
regexCompiled is allocated.

The problem is that this happens only when match is found otherwise it works correctly

[image: regex1]

step after :

[image: regex1]

here is code of function :

```
char * WebServer::get_db_query(char * line) {
  const char * regex = "<sql\\s+db=(.+?)\\s+query=(.+;)\\s*\\\\>";
  size_t maxGroups = 3;
  char * ret = (char * ) malloc(sizeof(char));
  regex_t regexCompiled;
  regmatch_t groupArray[maxGroups];

  if (regcomp( & regexCompiled, regex, REG_EXTENDED)) {
    printf("Could not compile regular expression.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return NULL;
  };

  if (!regexec( & regexCompiled, line, maxGroups, groupArray, 0)) {
    char copy[strlen(line) + 1];
    strcpy(copy, line);
    copy[groupArray[1].rm_eo] = '\0';
    copy[groupArray[2].rm_eo] = '\0';
    matched = true;
    sprintf(ret, "%s;%s", copy+ groupArray[1].rm_so, copy+ groupArray[2].rm_so);
    printf("Match %s\n",
      copy+ groupArray[1].rm_so);
    printf("Match %s\n",
      copy+ groupArray[2].rm_so);
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  regfree( & regexCompiled);
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post text as pic. Always post text as text.

Comment: @alk ok sir ... have to remove them?

Comment: Making things better is a good idea, in most cases, yes. In this particular case you might like to keep  my recommendation in mind for your next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the `reg*()` functions is correct.

When by freeing the `regex_t` the program crashes this most often mean that the memory management has been messed up before.

And this is what is also happening inside the code you show:

This line

```
 char * ret = (char * ) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

allocates exactly one `char`, which made `ret` point to nothing more but an empty string.

And then here

```
 sprintf(ret, "%s;%s", copy+ groupArray[1].rm_so, copy+ groupArray[2].rm_so);
```

the code copies lots of data to were `ret` points.

Allocate to `ret` as much memory as needed. Only one `char` definitely is to few.

Answer (score 2):

With `char * ret = (char * ) malloc(sizeof(char));` you allocate just *one* char.

When later you do `sprintf(ret, "%s;%s", ..` you go well beyond this one char and so you corrupt memory.

Then at any later moment you may encounter the problem when the heap detects it has been corrupted.

Allocate more than one char.